# setHyphenation and breakStrategy don't work as expected in TextView

Tags: android, hyphenation

I was trying to adding hyphenation on breaking long words in TextView. For example, I have a textView which text is "Recommendations". Because the word is too long for one line, I want to get "Recommend-" in the first line and "ation" in the second line like this :

[image]

But In fact, I got

[image]

Here's what I have for the TextView :

```
<TextView
   android:id="@+id/textViewid"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:text="@string/long_text"
   android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
   android:hyphenationFrequency="full" />
```

I have tried different combination of breakStrategy value and hyphenationFrequency value, but didn't make it work.
Any idea of why it behaves this or other ways to make hyphenation working?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I have the same problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479985/hyphenationfrequency-not-working-as-expected

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hyphens are not added at line endings to join words in some languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57479985/hyphens-are-not-added-at-line-endings-to-join-words-in-some-languages)