# Hyphens are not added at line endings to join words in some languages

Tags: android, textview

I have the following `TextView` within a `ConstraintLayout`:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
        ... />
```

When the text is too long to fit in one line, it will break into two lines. However, if the system language is set to Swedish it will break in the middle of words without adding a hyphen, like so:

`Some text that is br
oken into two lines`

I'm not sure if this is an accurate example, but you get the idea.

What I want is this:

`Some text that is br-
oken into two lines`

**It does work when the system language is set to English. But it should also work for Swedish.**

I have tried all possible combinations of `android:breakStrategy="..."` and `android:hyphenationFrequency="..."` on the `TextView`.

```
compileSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
minSdkVersion 28
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyphens are only added to connect words in line breaks if the language is set to English. This is probably a bug. Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37087785 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37010641 https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/79936443

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem comes from localization and characters encoding in different languages.

I suppose you are using the translation editor to support localization. Try getting the string of each textView (etc...) and converting it to utf-8 format using this:

```java
URLEncoder.encode(your string, "utf-8");
```

Then set the textView text to this string:

```java
textView.setText(your string);
```

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Using TextView.setTextLocale(Locale) to for example Locale.US works, but is probably not a good idea?

Comment: I don't think it's a bad idea but there must be a more generic solution. From what i understood you have swedish translation for the same text in english ? In this case setting the text locale of the textview will force it to use the english text. But in the other case, if you don't intend to translate your application and the problem is coming from the system language try setting your whole application locale to english us (in the first activity of your app).

Comment: Yes, I have Swedish translations for English strings. Actually, calling TextView.setTextLocale(Locale.US) does not change the text to English, it's still Swedish. And it will make sure hyphens are added properly. However, it's not perfect as hyphens are not added after special characters å, ä ö. I'm also worried about other potential side effects, my app supports a lot of different languages.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This is probably caused by a bug in the platform. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Not every languages is available for hyphenation in every Android version. E.g. Swedish and Polish are not available in Android API 33; they should be with the following Android release.
To perform proper hyphenation Android needs the language "dictionary" which are stored here: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:external/hyphenation-patterns/;l=1?q=hyphenation-&sq=

When it doesn't have the language dictionary available, it tries to break as best as it can, based on the available space.